# Unable to Print the Content of a Structure

Tags: c, struct

I want to print the content of the book record as defined in the `print_book()` function. Here is the code. My intention is to use the function to print any `struct` of type Book.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void print_book(struct Book book);

struct Book
{
    int id;
    char *title;
    char *author;
    int pages;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct Book book_1;
        book_1.id = 23;
        strcpy(book_1.title, "Java! A Complete Reference");
        strcpy(book_1.author, "Ryna Dahl");
        book_1.pages = 876;

    print_book(book_1);
    return 0;
}

void print_book(struct Book book)
{
    printf("BOOK\n");
    printf("Book ID: %i\n", book.id);
    printf("Book Ttitle: %s\n", book.title);
    printf("Book Author: %s\n", book.author);
    printf("Number of Pages: %i\n", book.pages);
}
```

Here is the error I am receiving in the console

```
muyiwa@muyiwa-HP-Pro-3010-Microtower-PC:~/Documents/C$ clang -o struct_pointer struct_pointer.c 
struct_pointer.c:4:24: warning: declaration of 'struct Book' will not be visible outside of this function [-Wvisibility]
void print_book(struct Book book);
                       ^
struct_pointer.c:22:16: error: argument type 'struct Book' is incomplete
    print_book(book_1);
               ^~~~~~
struct_pointer.c:4:24: note: forward declaration of 'struct Book'
void print_book(struct Book book);
                       ^
struct_pointer.c:26:6: error: conflicting types for 'print_book'
void print_book(struct Book book)
     ^
struct_pointer.c:4:6: note: previous declaration is here
void print_book(struct Book book);
     ^
1 warning and 2 errors generated.
muyiwa@muyiwa-HP-Pro-3010-Microtower-PC:~/Documents/C$ clang -o struct_pointer struct_pointer.c 
struct_pointer.c:4:24: warning: declaration of 'struct Book' will not be visible outside of this function [-Wvisibility]
void print_book(struct Book book);
                       ^
struct_pointer.c:16:17: error: variable has incomplete type 'struct Book'
    struct Book book_1;
                ^
struct_pointer.c:16:12: note: forward declaration of 'struct Book'
    struct Book book_1;
           ^
struct_pointer.c:26:24: warning: declaration of 'struct Book' will not be visible outside of this function [-Wvisibility]
void print_book(struct Book book)
                       ^
struct_pointer.c:26:6: error: conflicting types for 'print_book'
void print_book(struct Book book)
     ^
struct_pointer.c:4:6: note: previous declaration is here
void print_book(struct Book book);
     ^
struct_pointer.c:26:29: error: variable has incomplete type 'struct Book'
void print_book(struct Book book)
                            ^
struct_pointer.c:26:24: note: forward declaration of 'struct Book'
void print_book(struct Book book)
                       ^
2 warnings and 3 errors generated.
```

I have tried all possible means, and on checking other sources, my code looks correct.

Comment: Move the struct definition to be above the function declaration.

Comment: I've removed the C++ tag, since this code appears to compile without errors as C++. Avoid tagging both languages unless you have good reasons.

Comment: Unrelated, `strcpy(book_1.title, "Java! A Complete Reference");` What is the *target* of that string copy ? the `title` member of a book, right ? and what does that point to?  That mistake is made *twice*. Your code is about to ride a crash fest once you fix this compilation problem.

Comment: I have moved it, It compiles, but the output of my program is `Segmentation fault`

Comment: @WhozCraig and apparently it did ; )

Comment: Thank you @WhozCraig. It has worked perfectly after I removed the `strcpy()` and I did the direct assignment of the string.

Comment: In that case, notice that your `title` member is now pointing to a read-only memory area; the string literal. Any attempt to change its contents will result in another crash. Assigning it like that may even be an undefined behaviour, i am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

### Scopes of Declarations

When something is newly declared in a function parameter, its scope (the portion of source code in which it is visible) is limited to the function declaration. So, in `void print_book(struct Book book);`, `struct Book` declares a type that is known only inside that declaration. When the definition of `struct Book` appears later, it is a different `struct Book`.

If you put the definition of `struct Book` first, outside of any function, then its scope is the rest of the translation unit (the file being compiled along with any files it includes with `#include`). Then, when  void print_book(struct Book book);`appears later, this`struct Book` will not define a new type; it will refer to the type that is already in scope.

Lesson: Never make `struct Name` inside a parameter declaration the first appearance of `struct Name` in the code.

Note that you do not need to fully define the structure first. Merely putting a `struct Book;` first would inform the compiler there is a type `struct Book` with file scope. You could put the definition later (but before the compiler needs to know about the members of the structure).

### Allocation of Memory

In this code:

```
strcpy(book_1.title, "Java! A Complete Reference");
strcpy(book_1.author, "Ryna Dahl");
```

no memory has yet been allocated for `book_1.title` or `book_1.author`. These members are merely pointers that have not been given a value. To use `strcpy` correctly, you must allocate memory for the strings and set the pointers to point to that memory.

You can just set the pointers to point to the string literals directly:

```
book_1.title  = "Java! A Complete Reference";
book_1.author = "Ryna Dahl";
```

That sets the members to point to strings that you should treat as constants. If you want to have modifiable memory, you could do this:

```
//  Make temporary pointers to the string literals.
char *Title  = "Java! A Complete Reference";
char *Author = "Ryna Dahl";

//  Allocate memory for copies, including the terminating null characters.
book_1.title  = malloc(strlen(Title)  + 1);
book_1.author = malloc(strlen(Author) + 1);
if (!book_1.title || !book_1.author)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error, unable to allocate memory.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

//  Copy the strings into the allocated memory.
strcpy(book_1.title,  Title);
strcpy(book_1.author, Author);
```

Generally, if you allocate memory in this way, you should call `free` to release it when you are done using it. (In general-purpose multiuser operating systems, this can be omitted when the program is terminating, as the operating system will reclaim all memory.)

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TITLE_SIZE (128)
#define AUTHOR_SIZE (128)

struct Book
{
    int id;
    int pages;
    char title[TITLE_SIZE];
    char author[AUTHOR_SIZE];
};


void print_book(struct Book book);

int main(void)
{
    struct Book book_1;
    book_1.id = 23;
    strcpy(book_1.title, "Java! A Complete Reference");
    strcpy(book_1.author, "Ryna Dahl");
    book_1.pages = 876;

    print_book(book_1);
    return 0;
}

void print_book(struct Book book)
{
    printf("BOOK\n");
    printf("Book ID: %i\n", book.id);
    printf("Book Ttitle: %s\n", book.title);
    printf("Book Author: %s\n", book.author);
    printf("Number of Pages: %i\n", book.pages);
}
```

Comment: Code without explanation is not a good answer.

Comment: First, the structure should be before the function declaration statement because function USES this structure type as a parameter, second, the structure of two pointer members did not allocate enough space to hold the string, they just when defining a structure can allocate space for the two Pointers itself, so the two members should be are array